# Loading a lithium library only in certain environments

Tags: lithium

I have added li3_docs (https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/li3_docs) to my application but I don't want this library to load in production environment.  What is the best way to prevent the docs from being available in production environment? Initially I thought of adding this line to my *config/bootstrap/libraries.php*:

```
if(!Environment::is('production')) {
   Libraries::add('li3_docs');
}
```

This doesn't work because Environment class hasn't been loaded yet and I feel like it isn't wise to load this before the libraries loader.  So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hacky way would be add `Environment::set(new \lithium\net\http\Request())` before adding libraries.

Another way:

1. Add a configuration value when adding the library

   ```
   Libraries::add('li3_docs', array('devOnly' => true));
   ```
2. Update the default `Dispatcher::run` filter in `app\bootstrap\action.php` to something like this

   ```
   Dispatcher::applyFilter('run', function($self, $params, $chain) {
     Environment::set($params['request']);

     foreach (array_reverse(Libraries::get()) as $name => $config) {
       $devOnly = isset($config['devOnly']) && $config['devOnly'];
       $devOnly = $devOnly && Environment::is('development');
       if ($name === 'lithium' || $devOnly) {
         continue;
       }
       $file = "{$config['path']}/config/routes.php";
       file_exists($file) ? include $file : null;
     }
     return $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);
   });
   ```